# Update HTML datalist based on select box value - Google Apps/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm still new at HTML/JavaScript, so bear with me

I am trying to build a form with Google Apps script for entering quote request information.
I have a select box in which the user inputs the state of the address and an input box where they input the suburb. I also have a datalist element so that the user can select their suburb from the dropdown.

What I am struggling with is that I would like to have different values in the datalist for each state.
So, for example, if the user selects "State A", the suburb input list will have the options "A", "B", "C", but if the user selects "State B", the suburb input list will have options "D", "E", "F"

Since this is in Google Apps script, I have code for getting the appropriate options from a Google sheet, the problem is running code client-side to update the datalist.
I have tried searching around, but the suggestions I've found refer to don't seem to work.

Here is the HTML

```
<select id="cust_state" name="cust_state" onchange="get_suburbs()" required>
   <option selected disabled value="">- Select a state -</option>
   <option>State A</option>
   <option>State B</option>
   <option>State C</option>
</select>

<input type="text" list="cust_suburbs" id="site_suburb" name="site_suburb" required/>
   <datalist id="cust_suburbs">Update this list</datalist>
```

And here is the most recent js code I've tried

```
function get_suburbs() {
   var selected_state = document.getElementById("cust_state").value; 
   var suburbs = google.script.run.query_suburbs(selected_state);
   var dynamic_suburbs = document.getElementById("cust_suburbs");
      
   suburbs.forEach( function ( item ) { 
      // Create a new <option> element. 
      var option = document.createElement( 'option' ); 
      
      // Set the value using the item in the array. 
      option.value = item; 
      // Add the <option> element to the <datalist>. 
      dynamic_suburbs.appendChild( option ); 
   });
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution.

It turns out I wasn't handling the returned values properly and needed the success handler

New JS code

```
function get_suburbs() {
      var selected_state = document.getElementById("cust_state").value; 
      var suburbs = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(update_list).query_suburbs(selected_state);
   };
   
   function update_list(suburbs){
      var dynamic_suburbs = document.getElementById("cust_suburbs");
      
      suburbs.forEach( function ( item ) { 
         // Create a new <option> element. 
         var option = document.createElement( 'option' ); 
       
         // Set the value using the item in the array. 
         option.value = item; 
         // Add the <option> element to the <datalist>. 
         dynamic_suburbs.appendChild( option ); 
      });
   }
```